# JTable, how can I put icons in the header?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtableheader

i'm trying to render some icons in a JTable header without success. I've already tried something like this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingColumnHeaderswithIcons.htm
but it doesn't show any icon in the header. How can I reach this goal?

Comment: Show us what code you have so far. Try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can set the default `TableCellRenderer` used by the `JTable`'s `JTableHeader` which will affect all the columns, or you can specify the `TableCellRenderer` for a give `TableColumn` via the `setHeaderRenderer` method, your choice...

Comment: Are the images you use in the classpath?

Comment: @icza , I tried the code in my original post's link.

Comment: @Jens , yes they are

Comment: @Bellic93 If you try to open the file in a `FileInputStream` is that file found?

Comment: @Jens absolutely yes. I'm using a lot of .png in my project and they are all found by the program. I think that the `TableCellRenderer` linked in my post is wrong.

Comment: @Bellic93 I have tried the example by my own and it works fine. So the renderer should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is good code , but in fact when you load a picture using absolute path or relative path , this code is not portable .So it is better to load picture from a class. Levels :
1) Create a empty class with this name : ImageResources
2) Please copy your picture 
3) Please find ImageResources class in package explorer (in eclipse)  and do right click on it (ImageResources) and press "Paste" menuItem.
4) Finally you need a small change in your code like this

```
ImageIcon blueIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageResources.class.getResource(yourPictureName));
```

It is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Below method worked for me.

```
 MyTable.getColumn("ColumnName").setHeaderRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
               return new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/project/img/ImgName.png")));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit older, but I was only now faced with the same question.

Another approach is to override the TableModel's `getColumnName` function. **HTML formatted text is supported**.

[image: Example]

Here is the sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TableColumnHeaderIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
           
            TableModel tableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
                
                @Override
                public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
                    
                    // Build the html formatted text
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();           
                    sb.append("<html>");
                        sb.append("<img src=\"https://via.placeholder.com/16/007AAE/\">");
                        sb.append("&nbsp;Column Title");
                    sb.append("</html>");
                    
                    return sb.toString();
                }
                
                @Override
                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return 1;
                }
                
                @Override
                public int getRowCount() {
                    return 0; // No data required
                }                

                @Override
                public Object getValueAt(int i, int i1) {
                    return null; // No data required
                }
            };
            
            // Setup UI
            
            JScrollPane scrollPaneTable = new JScrollPane();
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
            scrollPaneTable.setViewportView(table);
            
            JFrame mdi = new JFrame("Test JTable Column Header with Icon");
            mdi.setSize(600, 400);
            mdi.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mdi.add(scrollPaneTable);
            
            mdi.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```